# How to set frequency capping for noty notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, session-cookies, noty

i am newbie.
I use "Noty" notification plugin for notifying users about updates on the website.
But its annoying when notification appears on every page while browsing.
I want to show this notification once per session. or (1 per hour).

I have created these example pages to explain properly.
You can check it [Here](http://play.songsmp3.link/account/user/frkmusic/index.html)
You will notice that notification appears on loading every page, i want to load this only once per session/hour.

View Source Code of the page

Comment: You need to store the _session_. Either in cookies or in localStorage. But don't ask how! Use the search engines.

Comment: Adding to what @Vohuman suggested: When you found an idea, started implementing but something specific does not work, you are welcome to come back to SO, we're all coders here, willing to help with specific coding problems.